# Selecionar 3 valores random em tabela mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Estou a tentar fazer uma alteração num código que vai ler numa tabela mysql o seguinte:

```sql
$getmaps = safe_query("SELECT * FROM ".PREFIX."cup_maps WHERE mappack='".$set['mappack']."'");
   while($mp=mysql_fetch_array($getmaps)) {
       $maps.='<option value="'.$mp['map'].'">'.$mp['map'].'</option>'; 
   }
```

em PHP para selecionar os "Mapas" vou ter o seguinte:

```php
{
      $select_map = 'Map Option #1<br>';
      $select_map.= '<select class="form-control" name="map1">'.$maps.'</select><br>';
      $select_map.= 'Map Option #2<br>';
      $select_map.= '<select class="form-control" name="map2">'.$maps.'</select>';
  }
```

Na Option 1 e Options 2 vai aparecer uma drop down list dos mapas que estão na tabela para o respectivo "map pack"

O que eu queria era que na option 1 e 2 em vez de ser uma drop down list, mostrar um "mapa" random da tabela em cada uma das options.

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Você pode ordenar o resultado de sua busca de maneira aleatória através do [ORDER BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) e da fução [RAND()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand). Veja:

```
SELECT * FROM ".PREFIX."cup_maps WHERE mappack='".$set['mappack']."' ORDER BY RAND()
```

Espero ter ajudado, abraço!